# hatcher's book about the wedge sum and a deformation retract

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was reading  Hatcher's book ,and I can't really understand how to get the wedge sum ,is it just that i combine my spaces with a single point ?  and for example he says that the complement R^3 -A where A is a circle deformation  retracts to the wedge sum of S^1 & S^2, he explains it but i can't understand it so  i was wondering if anyone can clarify it to  me .thank you

Comment: If you understand well quotient space, there is no problem. The wedge sum of $(X,x)$ and $(Y,y)$ is the quotient space $(X \coprod Y)/(x \sim y)$. 
Intuitively, you "glue" X and Y together, by gluing $x$ to $y$ only and you don't touch the rest.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this part :)

Comment: Of course. The most intuitive example is the wedge of two circle which gives you a space homeomorphic to "**8**"

Comment: yes the doctor also gave us this example but my problem was how to get the wedge sum because i couldn't at first understand the definition , but now i guess i'm Ok . Thanks .

Comment: what about the deformation retraction of R^3-A to the wedge sum of S^1 & S^2?

Comment: I have to go but I can complete my answer tomorrow. Where exactly is the page where Hatcher is talking about this retraction ?

Comment: Ok, I really have to go but first you can see that $\mathbb R^3$ retract on $S^2 \cup D$ where $D$ is a diameter of $S^2$. 
After, you can see that moving $D$ does not change the retraction, in particular you can move $D$ such that the two endpoints of $D$ are the same, and then this space will be homeomorphic to $S^2 \vee S^1$

Comment: page 46 , example 1.23

Answer (score 2):

A pointed space $(X,x)$ is a topological space $X$ with a point $x \in X$.

The wedge sum $X \vee Y$ of two pointed spaces $X = (X,x)$ and $Y = (Y,y)$ is the quotient space $$(X \coprod Y)/(x \sim y)$$

Intuitively, you are taking two spaces $X$ and $Y$ and pasting them together just at one point. Here is the wedge of two circles :

[image: Wedge of two circles]

Finally the wedge sum has a good behavior with fundamental group. More precisely, if $X_{\alpha}$ are topological spaces, then $$ \pi_1(\bigvee_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha}) \cong \ {\Large{*}}_{\alpha \in A} \pi_1(X_{\alpha})$$

You can prove the last isomorphism with the Van Kampen's theorem.

Comment: i understood this from your comments and i appreciate your help.

Comment: the question that remains is about the deformation retract of R^3-A ,A a circle, to the wedge sum of S^1& S^2, because i can't really understand it the way Hatcher does it .